# MVVM Opening windows while keeping View and View Model decoupled

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

I'm trying to use the MVVM pattern for the first time but I'm struggling with opening Views while keeping them decoupled from the View Models. I'm using a `DialogService` class (IDialog.cs below) which was part of an MVVM tutorial on YouTube. The `DialogService` works fine as long as it's being accessed from the MainWindow which has an instance of the `DialogService`.

The problem is that I need to open multiple `TradeView` from my `TradeManagerViewModel` which doesn't have an instance of `DialogService`. I can't create another instance of the `DialogService` because I would need to register all of the View/ViewModel mappings for every instance I create. I can't use the `DialogService` instance from my `MainWindowViewModel` because my `TradeMangerViewModel` doesn't have a reference to the instance of my `MainWindowViewModel`. In the main window view model I can't make `public readonly IDialogService dialogService;` static because then I can't assign the `dialogService` parameter passed in the `MainWindowViewModel` constructor.

The only other way I can think of is to create a separate singleton class which holds the instance of `DialogService` so the same instance can be accessed from both View Models (and future ones I've not yet written). But I've also read lots of different opinions about singleton classes and most of them suggesting that you shouldn't ever really need to use them. So I have I found an exception to that opinion? or is there another way I can/should go about this?

App.xaml.cs (Changes here were also taken from the YouTube video)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        IDialogService dialogService = new DialogService(MainWindow);

        dialogService.Register<TradeViewModel, TradeView>();
        dialogService.Register<TradeManagerViewModel, TradeManager>();

        var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(dialogService);

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

IDialog.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows Windows/Dialogs to be opened and closed without coupling the View to the ViewModel
/// </summary>
public interface IDialog
{
    object DataContext { get; set; }
    bool? DialogResult { get; set; }
    Window Owner { get; set; }
    void Close();
    bool? ShowDialog();
}

/// <summary>
/// Registers a dictionary of View Models to the the correct Views allowing the correct View to be displayed when an instance of a View Model is instantiated
/// </summary>
public interface IDialogService
{
    void Register<TViewModel, TView>() where TViewModel : IDialogRequestClose
                                       where TView : IDialog;

    bool? ShowDailog<TViewModel>(TViewModel viewModel) where TViewModel : IDialogRequestClose;

}

/// <summary>
/// Creates an Event Handler which handles close requests for the dialog
/// </summary>
public interface IDialogRequestClose
{
    event EventHandler<DialogCloseRequestedEventArgs> CloseRequested;
}

public class DialogCloseRequestedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DialogCloseRequestedEventArgs(bool? dialogResult)
    {
        DialogResult = dialogResult;
    }

    public bool? DialogResult { get; }
}

public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    private readonly Window owner;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises the DialogService and sets its owner
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner">The Window which will own the DialogService. The main window of the application will probably be the best owner.</param>
    public DialogService(Window owner)
    {
        this.owner = owner;
        Mappings = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    }

    public IDictionary<Type, Type> Mappings { get; } //Used to store which type of View should be used with each ViewModel

    /// <summary>
    /// Register which View should be used with a ViewModel
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TViewModel">Type of ViewModel</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TView">Type of View</typeparam>
    public void Register<TViewModel, TView>()
        where TViewModel : IDialogRequestClose
        where TView : IDialog
    {
        if (Mappings.ContainsKey(typeof(TViewModel))) //If a mapping already exists for this type of ViewModel
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Type {typeof(TViewModel)} is already mapped to type {typeof(TView)}");
        }

        Mappings.Add(typeof(TViewModel), typeof(TView)); //Otherwise create a new mapping
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the correct View for the given ViewModel and subscribes to the close request handler
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TViewModel"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="viewModel">ViewModel which you want to open the mapped View for</param>
    /// <returns>Returns bool dialog result</returns>
    public bool? ShowDailog<TViewModel>(TViewModel viewModel) where TViewModel : IDialogRequestClose
    {
        Type viewType = Mappings[typeof(TViewModel)]; //Get the type of View associated with this type of ViewModel from the Mappings Dictionary

        IDialog dialog = (IDialog)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType); //Create an instance of the mapped view

        EventHandler<DialogCloseRequestedEventArgs> handler = null;

        // When the handler is called, unsubscribe from the event as we no longer need to listen to it once the View has been closed
        handler = (sender, e) =>
        {
            viewModel.CloseRequested -= handler;

            if (e.DialogResult.HasValue)
            {
                dialog.DialogResult = e.DialogResult;
            } else
            {
                dialog.Close();
            }
        };

        //Subscribe to the CloseRequested event
        viewModel.CloseRequested += handler;

        dialog.DataContext = viewModel;
        dialog.Owner = owner;

        return dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel
{

    public readonly IDialogService dialogService;

    public MainWindowViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        this.dialogService = dialogService;

        //Load settings etc. removed.

        //This works here, but dialogService isn't accessible in TradeManagerViewModel:
        var tradeManagerViewModel = new TradeManagerViewModel(filePath);
        bool? result = this.dialogService.ShowDialog(tradeManagerViewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: ViewModels shouldn't communicate/know of each other directly. Look into a mediator implementation to handle this. [Josh Smith - Mediator Prototype](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/a-mediator-prototype-for-wpf-apps/)

Comment: Thank you I will look into mediators. But if the ViewModels shouldn't know of each other then wouldn't a separate singleton class with a reference to the DialogService be a simpler solution in this case?

Comment: Yes, I would agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would benefit from a IoC container, as proposed by others, but I don't think you should start with Prism. Start small, use the IoC container in MVVM Light, there are plenty of examples showing you how to write applications using that library.

You can also take a look att the samples of [MVVM Dialogs](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/mvvm-dialogs/tree/master/samples/net), there are numerous examples where one setup a dialog service in a IoC container.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for decoupling, in general, is to use Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control. You can use any DI Container (as Unity).

Also, you can use an MVVM Framework like [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism) which can help you to create the whole application loosely coupled and maintainable.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I've been looking at Prism, but so far all of the provided examples I've looked at for version 7 show how to navigate using regions within the main window. Notification requests open a new window but the custom notification example just passes a custom user control to a pre-made window. I need to open a custom window which doesn't have a title bar and control box (I.e. minimise, maximise and close buttons). Can you point me in the right direction please as I'm struggling to figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> But I've also read lots of different opinions about singleton classes and most of them suggesting that you shouldn't ever really need to use them.

That's plain wrong. In fact, singletons are really helpful for enabling instances to communicate that do not know of each other. I'd go with a weakend statement like `only make those classes a singleton that need to be one`, but there's no reason at all to completely avoid singletons.